# msql query FROM another msl query

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL, so I am not too sure how to go about this query that I have to do ...
I have multiple tables which all have 2 columns that i want to take (`date_added` and `path`).

So I did an `Union select ("date_added" and "path")` for each table. So I now have a table with all rows from all the tables I want:

```
SELECT `date_added`, `path` FROM `art_1` UNION SELECT `date_added`, `path` FROM `art_5484`
```

This works fine, but now I need to get the row with the lowest date ( I use min function). So I want to do select on the table that I got from my last query so I do:

```
SELECT `path`  
FROM cross_join = (SELECT `date_added`, `path` FROM `art_1` UNION SELECT `date_added`, `path` FROM `art_5484`)
WHERE `date_added` = MIN(`date_added`)
```

But this doesn't work; I am guessing it's a syntax error, but i can't see where ...
if anybody could help me out, that would be great !

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", does it return an undesired result, or error?

Comment: What is `cross join` supposed to be?

Comment: @ Reisclef it returns an error, a syntax error, but i can't see where...

Comment: @GordonLinoff my bad, i was going to call it union_select .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the minimum date is to use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT `path`  
FROM (SELECT `date_added`, `path` FROM `art_1` UNION ALL
      SELECT `date_added`, `path` FROM `art_5484`
     ) a
ORDER BY date_added DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note:  this returns only one value, even if when there are duplicates.  Also, I changed the `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.  You should use `UNION ALL` by default, because `UNION` incurs the overhead of removing duplicates.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a lot !
Is it possible to retrieve the second most recent  `date_added` with this order by method ?

Comment: found how to get the n most recent `date_added`: just add `OFFSET n;` at the end of your code. Thanks again